# current_setting with -v option

Tags: postgresql, psql

I'm trying to call this sql file that drop triggers with a certain name :

```
DO $$
DECLARE
    r RECORD;
    v_trig_name text := current_setting('trig_name', true); -- Récupération de la valeur de la variable
BEGIN
    FOR r IN (SELECT event_object_table, trigger_name
              FROM information_schema.triggers
              WHERE trigger_name=v_trig_name)
    LOOP
        EXECUTE 'DROP TRIGGER IF EXISTS ' || quote_ident(r.trigger_name) ||
                ' ON ' || quote_ident(r.event_object_table) || ';';
    END LOOP;
END $$;
```

With this psql command :

```
psql -d dbtest -f /var/lib/postgresql/data/dump/drop_triggers.sql -U srhbatch -v trig_name='trigger_test'
```

But when I get a liste of my db triggers, 'trigger_test' is still here. Moreover, when I remove the 'true' option from current_setting, I get an error message like this :

```
ERROR:  unrecognized configuration parameter "trig_name"
```

I use the -v option on other sql files, but with this one I can't make it work. Maybe it is related to the fact that I use it with plpgsql ?
I someone have any advice ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A `DO` statement is a string literal, and you cannot substitute a `psql` variable inside a string literal. Moreover, `psql` variables are not read with `current_setting()` — that is for configuration parameters. `psql` variables are accessed with a `:` prefix.

With `psql`, the simplest solution is to use `\gexec`:

```
SELECT format(
          'DROP TRIGGER %I ON %I.%I',
          trigger_name,
          event_object_schema,
          event_object_table
       )
FROM information_schema.triggers
WHERE trigger_name = :'v_trig_name'
\gexec
```

`\gexec` is used instead of `;` and executes every result row as an SQL statement.

Comment: I'm not sure if I understood your answer, but 'trig_name' is the name of the variable I want to use to drop triggers named 'trigger_test', like I indicated it in psql command : "-v trig_name='trigger_test'"

Comment: Sorry, I misunderstood your question.